# web api 2 singleton

Tags: asp.net-web-api, singleton

I have an in-memory object graph accessible via ASP.NET WEB API 2. GET, POST, PUT, DELET code executes correctly except that the accessed collection is "untouched" when the next action methon is called. I use Fiddler to test and my own clients. Looks like the collection is reconstructed for every call. 
I however need a single object graph that is accessed by all clients. Can Web API be configured to use singleton data, like WCF? Or do I have to make the data a singleton myself?  I am testing in VS.2013, I don't have a dedicated OWIN host yet.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a message handler class that derives from DelegatingHandler.
2. Pass your graph into the constructor.
3. Add an instance of your handler to the config.MessageHandlers collection.
4. When a request passes through your message handler, add your graph to the properties collection of the request.
5. Create an extension method to make it easy to pull the graph out of the request object.
6. Make sure your graph is thread safe.

Comment: When I mark the data as static (VB: shared) it keeps its changed state across multiple requests. Which is less work than your recipe. When does Web API 2 instantiate a controller object and when does it dispose it?

Comment: @HerbertFeichtinger The pipeline is described in depth here http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001708/ch04.html  Not sure why you care though...